# Google Sheets Query Function not in

Tags: sql, google-sheets

as tow tables 
semn
rserv
but i want elements not exist in second table
=QUERY(semn!A:A;rserv!A:A;"select semn!A:A WHERE A NOT IN rserv!A:A ")

Comment: Hi, you have not provided enough information for anyone to assist you.  Please have a read over of https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ to get an idea of how to ask questions and what is needed for people to be able to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=FILTER(semn!A:A; isna(match(semn!A:A; rserv!A:A; 0)))
```